Connecting link layer and node layer of road network
I have a link layer and node layer showing US highway system, now I want to join the line layer with the node layer indicating the start and end point of the link. How to do this?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Field calculate a start_point field on the line layer using the expression:
 aggregate(layer:='station',
   aggregate:='array_agg',
   expression:="station_id",
   filter:=distance(start_point(geometry(@parent)), $geometry)<5)[0]

The expression will search for a start point in the layer station that's within a distance of less than 5 of the lines start point and fetch the points station_id attribute.
Replace station with the name of your point layer, and station_id with the attribute you want to join, and 5 with the distance tolerance (in the units of your coordinate system).
Then join the end point:
 aggregate(layer:='station',
   aggregate:='array_agg',
   expression:="station_id",
   filter:=distance(end_point(geometry(@parent)), $geometry)<5)[0]

The output will have two new columns with start and end attributes:

